# How do we make a kick command with userid?

Tags: discord, command, discord.js, bots

So how do we detect the userID with the kick command below?

So below is my kick command and whenever I kick a person I need to mention them (?kick @test) I want to kick a user by their user id (?kick 354353) and their mentions.

```
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log('I am ready!');
});

client.on('message', message => {
  // Ignore messages that aren't from a guild
  if (!message.guild) return;


  if (message.content.startsWith('?kick')) {
    if (member.hasPermission(['KICK_MEMBERS', 'BAN_MEMBERS'])) 
    return;
    
    const user = message.mentions.users.first();
    if (user) {
      const member = message.guild.member(user);
      if (member) {
        member
          .kick('Optional reason that will display in the audit logs')
          .then(() => {
            message.reply(`Successfully kicked ${user.tag}`);
          })
          .catch(err => {
            message.reply('I was unable to kick the member');
            // Log the error
            console.error(err);
          });
      } else {
        // The mentioned user isn't in this guild
        message.reply("That user isn't in this guild!");
      }
      // Otherwise, if no user was mentioned
    } else {
      message.reply("You didn't mention the user to kick!");
    }
  }
});

client.login('TOKEN');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend setting up [Arguments](http://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/commands-with-user-input.html) if you plan to make more commands that take user input.

However if you're not interested in fully setting up arguments, you can just slice the message and grab the id. You will then need to fetch the member object, make sure to make your function is **async** for this, or use `Promise#then` if you prefer.

```
if (message.content.startsWith('?kick')) {
    if (member.hasPermission(['KICK_MEMBERS', 'BAN_MEMBERS'])) 
    return;
   const memberId = message.content.slice(' ')[1];

   if (memberId) {
      const memberToKick = await message.guild.members.cache.fetch(userId);

      memberToKick.kick('Optional reason that will display in the audit logs')
          .then(() => {
            message.reply(`Successfully kicked ${user.tag}`);
          })
          .catch(err => {
            message.reply('I was unable to kick the member');
            // Log the error
            console.error(err);
          });
   }
}
```

Comment: const memberToKick = await message.guild.members.cache.fetch(userId);
                         ^^^^^

SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function

Comment: Like I said in my answer: *make sure your function is **async** for this*

Comment: You can do this by changing your message event header to `client.on('message', async message =>`